# Can a system call have local variables and remember their values?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, system-calls

We are supposed to make a system call for producer consumer problem.
We have decided to initialize 3 semaphores(empty, full, lock) in the system call and then we will pass arguments to the system call

The first time it gets called with parameter *0*, it will execute **down(&sem)** on the three semaphores.  (Function from the linux/semaphores.h library)

Now, after this call, the producer will go on to produce items. When it leaves its critical section, it will call the system call again with parameter *1* to call **up(&sem)** on the three semaphores.

Now my concern is, do the variables initialized in system calls (the local variables of system calls) keep their values between multiple calls or do they reset to the initial on each call.

That is, if my system call has a semaphore full=10. And that gets decremented to 9,
Will it remember it as 9 on the next call or will it start again from 10?

Comment: 'if my system call has a semaphore full=10. And that gets decremented to 9, Will it remember it as 9 on the next call or will it start again from 10?' well, if OS semaphores lost units between calls, they would be useless.  That said, your question is a little confusing - if you have a semaphore pointer/reference/instance/whatever, you must ensure that it doesn't fall out of scope or otherwise made inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin. Your answer does make sense.